# Create Rules to forward emails sent to Distribution Group

Tags: office365, email-forwarding

We are using Office 365, and I need some help in creating mail flow rule that forward emails sent to Distribution Group.

I did try to create mail flow rule, however receive error message as "SentTo predicate does not allow distribution groups."

Thanks in advance

Comment: Currently working through a similar issue.  Shared Mailbox solution should work, but setting the Message>To field condition for the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the workaround provided by @Ravi (and in the link) is handling the From condition (also note that the "to box contains..." is only available when "Sender is located outside the organization" first condition is set).

Mike Wieggers has found a [way to accomplish and answer your question here](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/01/29/exchange-365-transport-rules-distribution-groups/)

1. create a **shared mailbox**
2. setup email forwarding from that mailbox to the desired Microsoft 365 group
3. use the shared mailbox in a Mail Flow / New-TransportRule

FWIW My goal is the same as yours (in the Mail Flow rule) :

- (Apply this rule if) using a Microsoft 365 group as a condition
- (Do the following) using a Microsoft 365 group as a ForwardTo target

> For the condition to work (Exchange complaining that it's a distribution group) I had to use : *"The sender address includes...Address includes any of these words"*
> and set it to the group's email as *"words or phrases"*

Answer (score 0):

Found http://www.adnsolutions.com/exchange-transport-rule-based-on-the-recipient-which-is-a-group/ and changing the condition "To box contains..." helped in fixing it.